# Text comes in between two sequential figures

Tags: graphics, pdf, ieeetran, ieee-style, fullpage

I have two figures, which I need each appearing in a single column, in an IEEE two-column style paper filling a single page. How to accomplish this?

**Problem:** Text comes in-between from elsewhere and can't control where to place each figure!

The order I put them is sequential and no text in-between in code:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\else
\fi
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell, booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}



\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
{\scalebox{0.75}{\includegraphics*{Fig4.pdf}}}\vspace{-0.1 cm}
\caption{flowchart 1 }
\label{fig:Fig_4}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
{\scalebox{0.75}{\includegraphics*{Fig5.pdf}}}\vspace{-0.1 cm}
\caption{flowchart 2}
\label{fig:Fig_5}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: ,@Hans -- This happens when there is not enough space remaining in the column for both figures. Try deleting some text before the figures or make the figures smaller and see what happens!

Comment: Do parameters like \textfraction apply to each column or just to the page as a whole?  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat

Comment: I solved the issue by putting `\begin{figure}[tp]` for the 1st fig. and `\begin{figure}[t]` for the 2nd. It is good to exploit `[place]` here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as unclear, as the problem can't be reproduced from the given code. For more advice on how to better receive help, provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to follow. However, I had solved the above problem as stated earlier.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be sure that the two figures are placed in the same column, put both images and captions in the same float. The only problem could be the default `\belowcaptionskip` in this class, but you can use the package `caption` to fix this, or simply insert by hand a vertical space between the figures, as in the MWE.

On the other hand, if the width of your images is less that the column  use `\centering` instead of the `center` environment, otherwise you do not need center anything.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{figure}[htb]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{flowchart 1 \label{fig:Fig_4}}
\vskip\abovecaptionskip 
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{flowchart 2\label{fig:Fig_5}}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[3-5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for the input! What does `lipsum[2]` or `lipsum[3-5]` do and why do you use its package?

Comment: @Hans the package `lipsum` simply write the paragraphs of dummy text (`\lipsum[1]` = "Lore ipsum dolor sit amet ... ") and it is only useful for examples or see the  layout of a document.